# Highlight the usernames uniquely

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

In my project, I am trying to highlight a text(only usernames) whenever represented with `@`. I am using the following function:

```
function replaceMessage(data, username) {
    return data.replace("@" + username, "<strong>@" + username + "</strong>");
}
```

This above function is working but if there are two valid users with names such as "Sam" and "Samuel" then the result after applying function is becoming something like this: 
           **`Sam`** and **`Sam`uel**   (Instead of `Samuel`).

How to solve this issue?

I am not that much good in using Regex, I tried the below function which is not working in IE8..

```
function replaceMessage(data, username) {
    return data.replace(/\b + "@" + username + /g, "<strong>@" + username + "</strong>");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need the special symbol `\b` which denotes a word break in a regular expression:

```
function replaceMessage(data, username) {
    var re = new RegExp('@' + username + '\\b', 'g');
    return data.replace(re, "<strong>$0</strong>");
}
```

Comment: +1 yep working.. one small doubt.. after adding `<strong>` I am doing something like this `var re = '<strong>@' + _chatUsername + '</strong>';` to replace the string again.. no issues right? (BTW, It is working) just caring for cross-browser.